# Как в Qt Designer создать QMessageBox?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

Пишу програмку на Pyside.
В Qt Designer создал QMainWindow и уже практически закончил программу. Но окна About и т.п. пишу вручную.
Как это делается из Дизайнера?
В нем нет класса QMessageBox.

**Upd:**
Как посоветовал ixSci сделал окно на классе QDialog в Дизайнере.
Потом добавил в основной код:

```
class Message(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Message, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QMessageBox` не предназначен для своего дизайна. Всё, что он представляет для изменения должно задаваться в коде. Если нужен какой-то свой MessageBox просто берите `QDialog` и делайте с ним всё, что нужно. `QMessageBox` есть ничто иное как наследник `QDialog`, с жёстко заданной структурой.

Comment: QDialog в дизайнере тоже нет.

Comment: @ИгорьЧе, http://screencast.com/t/rRh3BZQU9Td

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую

Comment: Окно получилось добавить. Но никак не удается привязать его к кнопке. Пишу: `QObject.connect(self.about, SIGNAL('activated()'), self.message.show())`

Comment: И у меня открываются сразу 2 окна Mainwindow и Message. Почему `self.message.show()` срабатывает при запуске программы, а не клике на пункт меню?

Comment: @ИгорьЧе, это другой вопрос. Задайте его отдельно, и в этом отдельном вопрос приведите Ваш код полностью.

Comment: Починил. Надо было метод show писать без скобок.

Comment: @ИгорьЧе, Если ответ Вам помог, тогда примите его как верный. Для этого нужно нажать галочку рядом с ответом

Comment: Благодарен вам за ответы. Я внес дополнения в свой вопрос, буду признателен за подсказку.

Comment: @ИгорьЧе, Вы добавили ещё один вопрос к уже существующему. Так не делается, один пост — один вопрос. Задавайте дополнительные вопросы отдельно.